# Как добавить в начале урл /город/ из параметра get в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть таксонометрия "City" и там элементы: Moskva, Piter и т.д.

Есть различные страницы на сайте:
site.ru/news1/
site.ru/page1/

Я хочу добавлять к каждой ссылке GET параметр с городом, например

site.ru/news1/?city=moskva и это должно превращаться в
site.ru/moskva/news1/

site.ru/news1/?city=piter в site.ru/piter/news1/

Получается, одна и та же новость в зависимости от GET параметра имеет разный урл.

Это возможно? Неправильный код для приличия:

```
function rewrite_rules() {
// Теги
add_rewrite_tag( '%city%', '([^&]+)', 'city=' );

// Правило перезаписи
add_rewrite_rule( '^([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?p=100&city=$matches[1]', 'top' );

// Скажем WP, что есть новые параметры запроса
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'city';
    return $vars;
} );
}

add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_rules' );
```